# How to make title-change call work in webkit2gtk?

Tags: python-3.x, webkit, gtk3

I am trying to port an old GTK webkit code written in python2 to webkit2 and python3 (Ubuntu has removed old webkit v1). The js code changes the title of the html, and python detected it to close it. However, it is not working in webkit2.
In the old code, there is the line

```
self.webview.connect('title-changed', title_changed) #title_changed is a python function, which will do something
```

which shows `TypeError: <WebKit2.WebView object at 0x7f14b687ecd0 (WebKitWebView at 0x557297cdb7c0)>: unknown signal name: title-changed`.

How to port this code to webkit2?
According to https://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkit2gtk/stable/WebKitWebView.html there is webkit_web_view_get_title (), but is there any way to detect change of title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `title` is a property, it automatically comes with a `notify` signal you can connect to. Use `notify::title`.

Use the following code, for example

```py
self.webview.connect('notify::title', title_changed)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please elaborate how to use `notify:title` in the python code? Could you provide a small code?

Comment: I have found the code and edited your answer (not approved yet)